# django template tag on multiple line

Tags: django

I am creating a custom django template tag by using such a code :

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def render_listing(context, *args, **kwargs):
   ... my code ...
```

This works well, but in my template, it seems that all parameters must be on a single line, for example :

this works:

```
{% render_listing param1=val1 param2=val2 ... paramN=valN %}
```

but on multiple lines, it does not work :

```
{% render_listing param1=val1 
                  param2=val2 
                  ... 
                  paramN=valN %}
```

I tried multiple escape sequences but I did not succeeded,

Is there a way to specify a template tag on multiple lines ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No, the Django template language does not support multiple line tags. See [ticket 8652](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8652), which was closed as WONTFIX, or [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-developers/wRKgnMIhl6g/A7MdArOlufwJ) from the django-developers mailing list.

Sometimes, if there is a repeated prefix, you can make it more readable by using the with tag. For example if you have,

```
{% render_listing param1=long.common.prefix.val1 param2=long.common.prefix.val2 param2=long.common.prefix.val3 %}
```

you could rewrite as

```
{% with prefix=long.common.prefix %}
{% render_listing param1=prefix.val1 param2=prefix.val2 param2=prefix.val3 %}
{% endwith %}
```

Often (but not always), a really long tag is an indication that you're putting too much logic in the template. See if you can move some of it into the view, model method, template tag or template filter.

Comment: In order to add to the answer, you can even annidate multiple with tags in case your line is still too long

Comment: Yes, you can nest multiple with tags, but the `{% endwith %}{% endwith %}...` tags begin to look a bit ugly.

Answer (score 19):

It's pretty straightforward to enable, though hackish:

```py
import re
from django.template import base
base.tag_re = re.compile(base.tag_re.pattern, re.DOTALL)
```

"Using" it is simple; one place I find it especially useful is `{% include %}` tags:

```
{% include 'my/sweet/modal-template.template' with
    message="Hey, do you really want to frob the widget?"
    yes="Heck yes I do!"
    no="No frickin' way!"
    icon="error"
%}
```

I haven't tested this in more recent versions of Django but I imagine it could be adapted; that worked at least back around 1.8. I should point out that in theory some tags that do custom parsing of their arguments could break; in practice I haven't had any trouble in the last ~10 years of Django programming.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on Django 1.11. Did you come up with a new trick for multi-line tags in the mean time? :) Thanks!

Comment: @VME that surprises me as the code to which this hack applies appears unchanged; be sure you are running this code before you parse any templates (for instance, you might import it at the end of `settings.py`).

Comment: @veuncent This still works in *Django 3.1*. I have tested from 1.11 - 3.1.

Comment: Where do you still this python code?

Comment: jfyi: this trick still works with Django v4.1.7